# Mac OSX 10.10.5 [Itunes 12.2.2.25]: Is there a shortcut for hearting a song on iTunes?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, music, shortcut

Having to tab back and forth between what I'm working on and iTunes only to heart a song by clicking the tiny heart in the play area is annoying.

If there isn't a short cut what would you suggest to make one?

I was thinking of automattor at first but wasn't sure if a service could work. I use some pretty complex work flows with alfred to but I'm not interested in having to engage another app to heart a song.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create a playlist?   Are you trying to play one song at a time?   Seems a simple playlist would be the best answer for you here...   no?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused as to why you're using the heart (meant to flag something as a favorite) as a play button?

Comment: @Charlie74 Perhaps I am confused. When I navigate to `For You`, Apple suggests albums and playlists that I might like. When I play those and hear a song I like I want to heart the song so apple knows to play more of the same.